# Does companyA with majority shares to companyB always/often have the decision?

Tags: private-company

I have read that companyA now have 60% shares of companyB. Does it mean that companyA have the business decisions for CompanyB? or this still depends on the agreement or board seat?

Comment: Do you mean 60% of the shares or 60% of the voting shares? That won’t always be the same thing.

Comment: This question is about companies and has nothing to do with personal finance and money.

Comment: where should i ask this in the stackexchange umbrella?

Comment: @DilipSarwate this could very well be about personal **investing**, since majority-owned subsidiaries can still be publicly traded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Company A can ask for a shareholder meeting at any time. And for any decision that doesn’t require more than 60% majority they will have the majority.

If Company B set up rules that some decisions need say 2/3rd majority then Company A would likely not have bought 60% of the shares.

Answer (score 4):

One of the immediate side effects of [gnasher729's answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/133024/22266) is that -- at the very first shareholder meeting -- Company A will appoint "their people" to Company B's board of directors.  It is they who will chose the CEO and President of Company B (or ensure that the existing CEO and President follow Company A's policies and goals).